# Error installing bootstrap using npm for node.js

Tags: typescript, npm-install, sharepointframework

Getting below error:

> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
>   (current:{os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Answer (score 0):

That's not really an error - it's a warning.

[fsevents](https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents) is a library that only works for MacOS. The warning just says that the library can't be installed for you, because you're not on a MacOS system:

> #### fsevents
>
> Native access to MacOS FSEvents in Node.js
>
> The FSEvents API in MacOS allows applications to register for notifications of changes to a given directory tree. It is a very fast and lightweight alternative to kqueue.
>
> This is a low-level library. For a cross-platform file watching module that uses fsevents, check out Chokidar.

You will also notice that `fsevents` is (often) defined under `optionalDependencies` in your package.json file.

This means you can skip installing it by running `npm install --no-optional`

Answer (score 0):

> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules\fsevents): SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any (current:{os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

It's a warning that we get from ***fsevents***. *It's not an error*

Basically it's a MAC OS specified but when we run on windows then it shows warning.
There is no reason to worry, you can skip it.
You can disable it by below command:

```
npm install --no-optional
```

You can also check [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11632) for more details